# Showing split polygons in different layers in QGIS

Tags: layers, qgis-3, splitting

I used the split feature to split a polygon into two parts.

Is it possible to show the split parts in sub-layers in the layers panel, so that I can hide them individually?

I am using QGIS 3.

Comment: If you right click on that layer and select duplicate, and then right click again and select filter, and give each a different filter query, that should work.  You will need a unique attribute in one of the fields to do this.  If you don't want to do that you could change the symbology on each layer using classified, and then on one layer remove one of the polys and on the other remove the other.

Comment: 1) Create another copy of the split polygons by Right-clicking>Export>Save Features as...fill in the form fields save and open it using the browser panel result of 2 identical layers; 2) Activate one layer>start the editing mode "Pencil" and remove unnecessary polygons>Save changes; by analogy, perform operations with the second layer - the result of two different layers...